# Weekly flex calculator

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is one of the first RSpec tests I've written, and I'm not really sure what the best practices are etc.

My question basically is: what would you do differently? What is good? What is bad?

The complete code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/asmand/d1ccbcd01789353c01c3).

Here is the class to be tested:

```
class WeeklyFlexCalculator

  attr_reader :params

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def calculate
    group_efforts(
      (params.start_date..params.end_date).map do |date|
        daily_effort(date)
      end.compact
    )
  end

  def group_efforts(result)
    weekly = result.group_by { |e| get_week_key(e[:date]) }
    weekly.map do |key,w|
      {
        year: get_year_from_week_key(key),
        week: get_week_from_week_key(key),
        weekTarget: get_target_sum(w),
        weekEffort: get_effort_sum(w),
        efforts: w
      }
    end.sort { |a, b| b.efforts[0].date <=> a.efforts[0].date }
  end

  def daily_effort(date)
      target = get_target(date)
      effort = get_effort(date)
      return if target == 0 && effort == 0
      {
        date: date,
        effort: effort,
        target: target,
        diff: effort - target
      }
  end

  def get_target_sum(efforts)
    efforts.inject(0){|sum,e| sum + e[:target]}
  end

  def get_effort_sum(efforts)
    efforts.inject(0){|sum,e| sum + e[:effort]}
  end

  def get_week_key(date)
    date.cwyear.to_s + "|" + date.cweek.to_s
  end

  def get_year_from_week_key(key)
    key.split('|')[0]
  end

  def get_week_from_week_key(key)
    key.split('|')[1]
  end

  def get_target(date)
    day_off?(date) ? 0 : params.user.hours_per_day
  end

  def get_effort(date)
    ts = get_timesheet(date)
    ts.nil? ? 0.0 : ts.TimeInHours
  end

  def day_off?(date)
    date.wday == 0 or date.wday == 6 or params.holidays.include? date.to_s
  end

  def get_timesheet(date)
    params.timesheets.select {|ts| ts.Date == date.to_s}.first
  end
end
```

And here is the test:

```
require './WeeklyFlexCalculator'

describe WeeklyFlexCalculator, "during Christmas week" do

  subject(:calculation) { WeeklyFlexCalculator.new(params).calculate }

  let(:params) do
    messages = {
      :start_date => Date.new(2013,12,23),
      :end_date => Date.new(2013,12,29),
      :holidays => ["2013-12-24", "2013-12-25", "2013-12-26"],
      :timesheets => [],
      :user => user
    }
    double(:params,messages)
  end

  let(:user) do
    messages = {
      :hours_per_day => 7.5
    }
    double(:user, messages)
  end

  let(:timesheet) do
    messages = {
      :Date => Date.new(2013,12,23).to_s,
      :TimeInHours => 5.0
    }
    double(:timesheet, messages)
  end

  context "with no work performed" do
    it { should have(1).item }

    context "the week calculated" do
      subject(:workweek) {calculation[0]}

      its([:year]) { should eq "2013" }
      its([:week]) { should eq "52" }
      its([:weekTarget]) { should eq 15.0 }
      its([:weekEffort]) { should eq 0.0 }

      context "the work efforts" do
        subject(:efforts) {workweek[:efforts]}

        it { should have(2).items }

        context "the first work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[0]}

          its([:target]) {should eq 7.5}
          its([:diff]) {should eq -7.5}
          its([:effort]) {should eq 0.0}
        end
      end
    end
  end

  context "with work effort on normal day" do
    before do
      params.stub(:timesheets => [timesheet])
    end

    it { should have(1).item }

    context "the week calculated" do
      subject(:workweek) {calculation[0]}

      its([:year]) { should eq "2013" }
      its([:week]) { should eq "52" }
      its([:weekTarget]) { should eq 15.0 }
      its([:weekEffort]) { should eq 5.0 }

      context "the work efforts" do
        subject(:efforts) {workweek[:efforts]}

        it { should have(2).items }

        context "the first work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[0]}

          its ([:effort]) { should eq 5.0 }
          its ([:diff]) { should eq -2.5 }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  context "with work effort on a holiday" do
    before do
      timesheet.stub(:Date => Date.new(2013,12,24).to_s)
      params.stub(:timesheets => [timesheet])
    end

    it { should have(1).item }

    context "the week calculated" do
      subject(:workweek) {calculation[0]}

      its([:year]) { should eq "2013" }
      its([:week]) { should eq "52" }
      its([:weekTarget]) { should eq 15.0 }
      its([:weekEffort]) { should eq 5.0 }

      context "the work efforts" do
        subject(:efforts) {workweek[:efforts]}

        it { should have(3).items }

        context "the first work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[0]}

          its ([:effort]) { should eq 0.0 }
          its ([:diff]) { should eq -7.5 }
        end

        context "the second work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[1]}

          its ([:effort]) {should eq 5.0}
          its ([:diff]) { should eq 5.0}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @CMW [There are reasons why we close questions that just link to code instead of editing the question for the OP.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/467/2041)

Comment: Don't suggested edits need to be approved by the OP anyway? In that case it's completely under their control, or is it?

Comment: @CMW that isn't how it works. other people approve the suggested edits by vote.

Comment: @Malachi, svick My apologies then, I didn't have that case yet of the community approving any edits on my questions. Only did so myself.

Comment: @CMW : the edits are always sent to the review queue but that is bypassed if you accept the edit, so it is whatever happens first, vote or OP approval

Comment: Is there still something wrong with the post that I could change? I mean, since it's still on hold?

Comment: @AndreasFinne StackExchange sites are moderated by the community - there are review queues for suggested edits, close votes, ...and reopen votes - see [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Answer (score 5):

## Spec

### The Good

There's not much here that needs changing.

- You only check one condition per `it` or `specify`
- Good use of `let`, `subject`, `before`, etc. to keep the test DRY and simple.
- Appropriate use of `#stub` for methods which are referentially transparent (when you say *#stub*, you are telling the reader of the test, "We don't care how many times this gets called, because it has no side-effects."

### Can be improved

There are some minor inconsistencies in indentation (see #daily_effort).

Some instances of `context` might be better as `describe` instead.  Use context to indicate a precondition; describe to indicate a class, method, or behavior being tested.

```
describe SomeClass

  context 'when things are setup a certain way' do

    describe 'the aspect of its behavior being checked' do
      its(:metasyntacticvariable) {should eq :foo}
      its(:meaning) {should eq 42}
    end

    describe 'a different aspect of its behavior being checked' do
      its(:shoe_size) {should eq 7}
      its(:hair_color) {should eq 'brown'}
    end

  end

  context 'when things are setup a different way' do
    # etc
  end

end
```

Here are a few of the `context` calls I would consider changing to `describe`:

```
context "the work efforts"
context "the first work effort"
context "the second work effort"
```

There's a little bit of missing test coverage:

- In #get_timesheet, the `.first` can be changed to `.last` and the test still passes.
- In #group_efforts, the entire `.sort {...}` can be removed without the test noticing.

## The code under test

### The good

There's a little more here that could be better, but overall the class has a lot going for it:

- Small, concrete methods
- Immutable
- Good names

### Could be improved

In #group_efforts, the sort can *probably* be changed from:

```
sort { |a, b| b.efforts[0].date <=> a.efforts[0].date
```

to:

```
sort_by { |e| e.efforts.first.date }
```

I say *probably* because the sort has no test coverage.

There's much that could be improved if attribute access were via accessor methods rather than by `[]`, but that goes outside the scope of this class and imposes changes on its collaborators.  For example, if an effort's target could be accessed by `effort.target` instead of `effort[:target]`, then this:

```
efforts.inject(0){|sum,e| sum + e[:target]}
```

could be changed to:

```
efforts.map(&:target).inject(0, :+)
```

The pipe separator "|" appears repeatedly.  It deserves a constant.

These methods:

```
  def get_year_from_week_key(key)
    key.split('|')[0]
  end

  def get_week_from_week_key(key)
    key.split('|')[1]
  end
```

are a little damp.  Consider:

```
  def get_year_from_week_key(key)
    split_key(key)[0]
  end

  def get_week_from_week_key(key)
    split_key(key)[1]
  end

  def split_key(key)
    key.split('|')
  end
```

In `#day_off?`"

```
date.wday == 0 or date.wday == 6 or params.holidays.include? date.to_s
```

Replace the `or` with `||`:

```
date.wday == 0 || date.wday == 6 || params.holidays.include?(date.to_s)                              |
```

`or` (and `and`) have odd (and often surprising) precedence rules.  They are not interchangeable with && and ||, a common source of bugs, and are seldom used in practice.

Comment: What about using rspec 2.0 expect vs should? https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md

Comment: @Fred, good point.  Note that it's not the method `should` that's deprecated, it's the use of the globally defined `should`.  The use of `should` in the form 'its(:foo) {should eq 1}` is not deprecated.